# Relatively compact set theorem from Billingsley's Convergence of Probability Measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability, inequality, continuity, compactness

[image]

x is a continuous function on [0,1] with uniform topology.

The part I don't understand is second from last equation, where we have inequality of x(t) and x(0) with sum. How can I make sense of that equation, or prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since\begin{multline}x(t)=x(0)+\left(x\left(\frac tn\right)-x(0)\right)+\left(x\left(\frac{2t}n\right)-x\left(\frac tn\right)\right)+\cdots+\\+\left(x\left(\frac{nt}n\right)-x\left(\frac{(n-1)t}n\right)\right),\end{multline}all  you have to do is to use the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple Without absolute values you have equality: just see that lots of terms on RHS cancel out. So all you need is triangle inequality.